# Railsのaccepts_nested_attributes_forの使い方を教えてください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

現在、Railsアプリを製作しています。
accepts_nested_attributes_forを使用しているのですが、【subjects_controller.rb】のsaveメソッドの前に、子モデル(cost)のカラムの値を取得するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

やりたい事は、子モデル(cost)のカラムの値を取得して、四則演算を行い、その後saveしたいです。
※ 以下のカラムの値は投稿用のため、意図的にnilにしています。

・環境
Rails 4.2.3
Gem cocoonを使用

・親モデル
subject

・子モデル
cost

【subject.rb】　※親モデル

```
has_many :costs, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :costs, allow_destroy: true
```

【subjects_controller.rb】

```
def create
    @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)

    ※この位置で子モデル(cost)のカラムの値を参照したいです。
    raise @subject.inspect、をしてみると親モデル(subjects)の<Subject id: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, customer: nil, subject: nil, remarks: nil>しか入っておらず、子モデル(cost)の値を参照できないです。

    respond_to do |format|
      if @subject.save
※途中省略

private

def subject_params
      params.require(:subject).permit(
        :user_id, :customer, :subject, :remarks,
        costs_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :subject_id, :material, :product, :pressure, :size, :quantity, :hvk, :fujii, :imamoto, :unit_price, :price_total, :hvk_total, :fujii_total, :imamoto_total, :selling_price, :selling_price_total, :grossmargin_rate, :gross_profit, :price_total, :remarks, :sign, :_destroy]
      )
end
```

【cost.rb】　※子モデル

```
belongs_to :subject
```

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

#### ※ 追記

四則演算させたい部分はnilになっていますが、以下を返します。

```
def create
    @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
    @hoge = @subject.costs
    raise @hoge.inspect
```

の結果です。

`<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Cost id: nil, user_id: nil, customer_id: nil, material: nil, product: "商品A", pressure: nil, size: nil, quantity: "10", hvk: "70", fujii: "80", imamoto: "100", unit_price: nil, price_total: nil, hvk_total: nil, fujii_total: nil, imamoto_total: nil, selling_price: "800", selling_price_total: nil, grossmargin_rate: nil, gross_profit: nil, remarks: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, sign: "1", subject_id: nil>]>`

Comment: そもそも`@subject`の値が　`user_id: nil` などというように全てnilですが、意図的ですか？　本来、値を入れたいはずだと思いますが。

Comment: また`@subject.costs`は何を返しますか？

Comment: すみません、投稿用にnilにしています。実際には親のモデル、子のモデルにも、各カラムに値は入っております。ただ、`@subject = Subject.new(subject_params)`の中には親モデルしか入っておらず、子モデルのカラムの値は参照できない状況です。具体的にはストロングパラメータ内の、子モデルの、`costs_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :subject_id, :material, :product, :pressure, :size, :quantity, :hvk, :fujii, :imamoto, :unit_price, :price_total, :hvk_total, :fujii_total, :imamoto_total, :selling_price, :selling_price_total, :grossmargin_rate, :gross_profit, :price_total, :remarks, :sign, :_destroy]
      )`のカラムの値をsaveメソッドの前に参照したいです。

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます。本文に追記させて頂きました。

Comment: `@subject.costs`参照できてますよね？　`sign: "1",`とありますし。

Comment: また　意図的にnilにしていることも本文に追加してください。スタックオーバーフローでは、コメントに記載するのではなく質問を改善していくスタイルが求められます。

Comment: `@subject.costs`は参照できるのですが、ここから子モデルのカラムである`sign: "1"` だけを取得したいのですが、それができない状況です。
`@subject.costs.sign` としても `sign: "1"` は取得できずに`undefined method "sign" for #<Cost::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f48c0fc5660>`エラーが発生します。

Comment: 回答に追記しました。あとから見た人が質問と回答だけ読んで意図がわかるように質問の編集をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for`についてはまったく関係ありません。
（というか`accepts_nested_attributes_for`についてはうまくいっているようです）

has_manyな子モデルを参照する場合ActiveRecordでは、
`hoge.foos`という形になりますので、

`subject.costs`で取得できます。
あとは得られたデータで四則演算しましょう。

`subject.costs`は配列のような動きをします(もちろん他の機能もあります)。
`costs`が必ずひとつという保証があるのであれば`subject.costs.last.sign`とすればよいですし、複数あるなら適切に`each`などで回して計算しましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます！eachメソッド使えば個別に値を取得できますね。＾＾気づけなかったです。明日試してみます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @poplot726 試して解決した場合は回答にチェックをお願いします。

Comment: 承知しました！解決した場合はチェックを入れるように致します。